# Mocha.js and Should.js to test express.js app

Tags: testing, express, mocha.js, should.js

How can I use Mocha.js and Should.js to effectively test that my express.js app is sending the correct data back?

The reason I ask is that sometimes, if `req.xhr` we send back the same data but in a different format, depending on the extension from the route. So, for that reason we want to ensure that the routes are performing the right conditions under the circumstances given.

Is there any way I can get express to send a result back that can be read by should.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mocha and request to do end-to-end HTTP testing. Here's an example, where app.js runs the server:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; // Avoids DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error for self-signed certs
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
var fs = require('fs');
var expect = require('expect.js');
var app = require("../../app.js");
var hash = function (file) { crypto.createHash('sha1').update(file).digest('hex') };

describe('Static tests', function () {
    it('should serve out the correct favicon', function (done) {
        var favicon = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../../public/img/favicon.ico');
        request.get('https://localhost:' + process.env.PORT + '/favicon.ico', function (err, res, body) {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.be(200);
            expect(hash(body)).to.be(hash(favicon));
            done();
        });
    });
});
```